# Modificación en el reconocimiento de operaciones elevadas a la potencia en SymPy

Tags: python

Como hago para que las operaciones elevadas a una potencia seas reconocida así **^** y no de esta forma `**`

Tengo este codigo:

```
from sympy import *    
x = Symbol('x')    
y = Symbol('y')    
print(diff(x**2, x))
```

Lo que hace es calcular la derivada. Con el comando `diff(funcion, variable)`
funciona, pero quisiera que en vez de poner `x**2`, pueda utilizar `^`

¿Hay alguna forma de lograr esto?

Answer (score 2):

No lo hagas :)

El doble asterisco como potencia viene heredado de la sintaxis de Python. Además, el [operador `^`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) tiene la funcionalidad de [disyunción exclusiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disyunci%C3%B3n_exclusiva).

`from libreria import *` lo que hace es importar ***todas*** las funcionalidades al *namespace* (espacio de trabajo). Aunque pueda paracer cómodo, se considera una mala práctica porque puede enmascarar otras funciones y pierdes la información de dónde provienen.

Editado: Dale un vistazo a [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/) que es otra opción interesante y el `^` trabaja como exponente ([ventajas y deventajas de Sage frente a SymPy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/SymPy-vs.-Sage))

Comment: No man pero imagina que usas tu el programa como usuario que no sabe nada de programacion, tu no sabrias que la potencia es asi ** sino que a lo mucho pensarias que es ^ por eso necesito que sea asi ^.

Comment: Ya, pero si uso tu programa, y sí se de programación, no me funcionaría (ya que estás haciendo una versión personalizada) y tampoco lo entendería porque en Python esperaría que `^` funcionara como algo distinto. Mira [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/) que quizás te sea más interesante.

Comment: Vale lo revisare amigo

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi misma pregunta porque me doy cuenta que si pongo el mismo codigo

from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')

y = Symbol('y')

print(diff(x**2, x))

PERO cambiando el print(diff('x^2', x))

El si va a reconocer ^ como potencia, pero igual quiero dejar la pregunta abierta por si hay otra forma sin tener que ponerlo entre comillas simples, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Esto funciona porque SymPy por defecto analiza las cadenas de texto que van entre comillas transformando el significado del operador. [Aquí tienes más información](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) del método que estás usando.